# Add social icons doesn't seem to the menu

Tags: html, wordpress

I add in the menu using custome link a facebook icon like this:

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
```

however I can't see it. It is there as I can click or inspect it but I can see it. I t seems to be behind the menu which has font color black.

What can I do to see the icon?

Answer (score 0):

is fontawesome are in your css? 
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/

Comment: I tried to insert it in the head of page but it removes my menu

Comment: fa-facebook needs fontawesome css in head page, you might want to inspect element to see why it removes or hide that menu. might conflict in class name or name id on the parent dom.

Answer (score 0):

You should you in your function.php

```
add_filter( 'storm_social_icons_networks', 'storm_social_icons_networks');
function storm_social_icons_networks( $networks ) {

    $extra_icons = array (
        '/feed' => array(                  // Enable this icon for any URL containing this text
            'name' => 'RSS',               // Default menu item label
            'class' => 'rss',              // Custom class
            'icon' => 'icon-rss',          // FontAwesome class
            'icon-sign' => 'icon-rss-sign' // May not be available. Check FontAwesome.
        ),
    );

    $extra_icons = array_merge( $networks, $extra_icons );
    return $extra_icons;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it right then it should be showing in your menu..

or

You can use a plugin for social media links.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-social-icons/
This is the plugin and you can add your social media links to this plugin.
A shortcode is used to display social media icons.
You can use it.

Shortcode '[cn-social-icon]'

This is easy and time saving solution.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you see it in the inspect but don't see in your dom make you sure you should looking for it in the dom, first solution is :

```
   <a href="#">
      <i class="icon icon-facebook"> </i>
   <a/>
```